# Windows application issue in array sum

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, sum

Given an array initialized with numbers, how can I add all of its elements without using LINQ or `foreach`?

My incomplete code is as follows:

```
namespace WindowsApplication5
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         method1(sum1);
         MessageBox.Show("The Sum Is = " + sum1.ToString(), "Addition",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageB…
      }
      int sum1;
      int[] str = new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; // i want to add this 4 values and to be printed on a messagebox//

      public int method1(int str)
      {
          sum1 = str;
          return sum1;
      }
   }
}
```

The output is showing *"the sum is = 0"*, instead of 10.

Thank you.

**P.S:** I don't want to use LINQ or `foreach`.

Comment: Ahh - how stupid of me - *that's* why Aliza can't use linq!!!!

Comment: I have added my answer below, but just a few comments on your code that should help you in your learning.  Method names should be descriptive 'method1' is a poor example. You are using global variables - Google why there are a bad idea.   Get into good habits now, they will serve you well for the future.

Answer (score 3):

For a start you have global variables which are bad. Without using `LINQ` or `Foreach` as you mentioned, try something like:

```
//Doesn't have to be a button click...just an example.
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int[] values = new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
   int result = Sum(values);
   MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
}

int Sum(int[] values)
{
   int sum= 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; ++i)
   {
       sum += values[i];
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest options that don't use `foreach` or `LINQ` would be to use either a `for` loop or recursion.
The recursive solution:

```
int Sum(int[] arr, int index = 0, int current = 0)
{
  if(index == arr.Length)
    return current;
  return Sum(arr, index+1, current+arr[index]);
}
```

Using a for loop:

```
int Sum(int[] arr)
{
  int result = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i<arr.Length; i++)
    result+=arr[i];
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To take the sum of an array, you can simply say: `int sum = myArray.Sum();`

To do so you need to have: `using System.Linq` since that's where the Sum extension method is defined.

If you don't have linq, then how about:

```
private int CalculateSum(int[] arr){
   int total = 0;
   foreach(int i in arr)
      total += i;
   return total;
}
```

Comment: its not applying, it says that int does not contain a definition for sum

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your comment that you don't want to use LINQ or foreach.  I'm not sure if you're using an older version of .NET without linq, but the only other way I can think of to sum an array is with a for loop

Comment: it is not working man, Sum(); is not in my context, i am not using LINQ

Comment: ya if it is done with a for loop then how the code will be? can u post it?

Comment: Even if you're not using LINQ, there shouldn't be any reason why you can't add a using directive for System.Linq.  Are you using .NET 3.5 or later?

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious about why you're opposed to a `for` loop.  Could you enlighten us?

**Unless I'm missing something, it seems like you've got two options:** 
1) use an existing method (in this case it would be the `.Sum()` method, in `LINQ`), or 
2) write a method yourself to compute the sum (that would be the `foreach` loop)

Comment: The question said: without a *foreach* loop - I suspect foreach is covered *next week* in class :)